# Javascript css html (why when i expand screen > 100px, i cant fix property)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I learning from frontend mentor,

my problem is when my screen < 1000px, I click at icon-hamburger then I expand screen > 1000px,why property unchanged?, how can I fix this problem?

i cant add all code because it limited from stackoverflow. thank for helping

index.html

```
 <header>
    <nav>
      <img class="logo" src="./assets/images/logo.svg" alt="">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">New</a>
        <a href="">Popular</a>
        <a href="">Trending</a>
        <a href="">Categories</a>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
        <img id = "icon-close" src="./assets/images/icon-menu-close.svg" alt="">
        <img id ="icon-hamburger" src="./assets/images/icon-menu.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

styles.css

```
:root{
      --mainwidth: 80%;
    }
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    header{
      border: solid pink 1px;
    }

    nav{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      border: solid green 1px;
      max-width: var(--mainwidth);
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px 0;
    }

    #icon-close, #icon-hamburger{
      position: relative;
      width: 20px;
      z-index: 9999;
      cursor: pointer;
    }


    #icon-close{
      display: none;
    }
```

```
nav .menu{
      /* border: solid red 1px; */
      /* display: flex when Desktop size*/
      display: none;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 5px;
    }


    .show-drop-menu{
      background: white;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 65vw;
      padding-top: 10vh;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: fixed;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){

      #icon-hamburger,#icon-close,.icon{
        border: solid yellow 1px;
        display: none;
      }

      nav .menu{
        display: flex;
      }

      .show-drop-menu{
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

scripts.js

```
const icon_hamburger = document.querySelector("#icon-hamburger");
const icon_close = document.querySelector("#icon-close");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

icon_hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    icon_hamburger.style.display = 'none'; 
    icon_close.style.display = 'flex';
    menu.style.display = 'flex';
    menu.classList.add("show-drop-menu");
});

icon_close.addEventListener("click", () => {
    icon_close.style.display = 'none'; 
    icon_hamburger.style.display = 'flex';
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    menu.classList.remove("show-drop-menu");
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRb6r.png)

Comment: can u add your html ?

Comment: i added html css and js.

Answer (score 0):

The only bug in this code is a class: .show-drop-menu, this css class is applicable to all the screen sizes but as for your requirement you don't need it when screen size>1000px. Sharing the resolved code below

```js
  const icon_hamburger = document.querySelector("#icon-hamburger");
  const icon_close = document.querySelector("#icon-close");
  const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

  icon_hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    icon_hamburger.style.display = 'none';
    icon_close.style.display = 'flex';
    menu.style.display = 'flex';
    menu.classList.add("show-drop-menu");
  });

  icon_close.addEventListener("click", () => {
    icon_close.style.display = 'none';
    icon_hamburger.style.display = 'flex';
    menu.style.display = 'none';
    menu.classList.remove("show-drop-menu");
  });
```

```css
  :root {
    --mainwidth: 80%;
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  header {
    border: solid pink 1px;
  }

  nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: solid green 1px;
    max-width: var(--mainwidth);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }

  #icon-close,
  #icon-hamburger {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;
  }


  #icon-close {
    display: none;
  }

  nav .menu {
    /* border: solid red 1px; */
    /* display: flex when Desktop size*/
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
  }




  @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

    #icon-hamburger,
    #icon-close,
    .icon {
      border: solid yellow 1px;
      display: none;
    }

    nav .menu {
      display: flex;
    }

    .show-drop-menu {
      display: none;
    }

  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .show-drop-menu {
      background: white;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 65vw;
      padding-top: 10vh;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: fixed;
    }

  }
```

```html
  <header>
    <nav>
      <img class="logo" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/508384/thief.svg" alt="" width="60px">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">New</a>
        <a href="">Popular</a>
        <a href="">Trending</a>
        <a href="">Categories</a>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
        <img id="icon-close" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/507465/align-arrow-up.svg" alt="" width="60px">
        <img id="icon-hamburger" src="  https://www.svgrepo.com/show/507098/cld-server.svg" alt="" width="60px">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Hope it solves your issue. :)